# How to navigate pages in react native side menu?

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

My code has react-native-router-flux and react-native-side-menu.

```
Home.js
...
onPress={Actions.login}

Login.js
...
onPress={Actins.home}

...
contentView.js
<Router>
...
 <Scene tabs initial>
 <Scene key="home" component={Home} />
 <Scene key="login" component={Login} />
...
</Scene>
</Router>

...
const menu=<MyMenu />
<SideMenu menu={menu} ...>
<ContentView ...>
</SideMenu>

MyMenu.js
...
onPress={Actions.login}
```

But When I click the button labeled "go to login", I can't go login page. How should I do for this issue?
Or is there a way to resolve this problem?
[image]